# "FATAL: cannot determine kernel version" when updating initramfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I download linux kernel-5.0.0 and try to compile and install it on my Ubuntu-18.04.3

the commands i used in /usr/src/linux-5.0:

```
sudo make mrproper

sudo make menuconfig

sudo make -j4

sudo make modules_install

sudo make install
```

at the result of last command, there is a error:

```
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.02173611831    

run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 5.0.02173611831 /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.02173611831

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.02173611831

FATAL: cannot determine kernel version
```

I have no idea why this is a "FATAL: cannot determine kernel version" and how can i fix it.

At the beginning, i skip it but then I find that the "cannot determine kernel version" always show up once i open vim like this.
[when i open vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIGde.png)

by the way, the strange numbers 5.0.02173611831 are (the kernel version) + (my numbers in university), i did the config when "sudo make menuconfig" as my teacher ask.

Comment: I suggest beginning the local version with a dash (hyphen). So instead of setting "Local version" to "2173611831" (in menuconfig), set it to "-2173611831" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error "FATAL: cannot determine kernel version", it turned out to be a misuse of 'cpp' in a ./configure script.

Other uses were like

```
# Double quotes because CPP needs to be expanded
for CPP in "$CC -E" "$CC -E -traditional-cpp" "/lib/cpp"
```

But this error came from a line

```
kernsrcver=`(echo "#include <$utsrelease>";
    echo "kernsrcver=UTS_RELEASE") |
    cpp -I $kernelbuild/include |
    grep "^kernsrcver=" | cut -d \" -f 2`
```

I changed the cpp line to (and it worked):

```
    cpp -I $kernelbuild/include -E - |
```